# String scattering diagrams with TikZ or other package in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am working on a paper and I need in the introduction to put a diagram. The diagram is the following (or something similar) and I was wondering how can I reproduce it in LaTeX code.[image: Diagram of a string scattering process]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/loop-space)'s purpose-built [`tqft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tqft) library:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tqft}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/cobordism/.style={draw},tqft/every boundary component/.style={draw}]
\pic [tqft/pair of pants];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

There are *many* customization options as well as other shapes and connection methods, if you need a substantial number of these diagrams. You may refer to the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tqft) for complete details.

Answer (score 2):

A TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (.5 and .25);
  \draw (-1,-2) ellipse (.5 and .25);
  \draw (1,-2) ellipse (.5 and .25);
  \draw (-.5,0) to[out=-90,in=90] (-1.5,-2);
  \draw (.5,0) to[out=-90,in=90] (1.5,-2);
  \draw (-.5,-2) to[out=90,in=90] (.5,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

With some pseudo-3D

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(-.2cm,-.2cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)}]
  \draw (0,0,0) circle (.5);
  \draw (-1,0,-2) circle (.5);
  \draw (1,0,-2) circle (.5);
  \draw (-.5,0,0) to[out=-90,in=90] (-1.5,0,-2);
  \draw (.5,0,0) to[out=-90,in=90] (1.5,0,-2);
  \draw (-.5,0,-2) to[out=90,in=90] (.5,0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I want rotate it? like by 90°. Can Simply I change the coordinates in draw commands, right?

Comment: Just add `[rotate=90]` to the `tikzpicture` environment like in `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]`. Also try reading the [TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (At least chapters 2-7). It contains a vast amount of examples and tutorials.